# Python regex with named group in conditional expression

Tags: python, regex

I'm having trouble getting a regex to work using a named group and a conditional expression. I've simplified the problem to the smallest possible example.

The regex `r"(?P<x>\d)(?(x)a|b)"` would seem to mean "match a digit, and if you matched a digit (named group `x`) also match an `a`, but if not, match `b`". This should be equivalent to `r"(\da|b)"`.

However, while it matches for the `yes` clause, it doesn't match the `no` clause:

```
>>> re.match(r"(?P<x>\d)(?(x)a|b)", "5a")
<re.Match object; span=(0, 2), match='5a'>
>>> re.match(r"(?P<x>\d)(?(x)a|b)", "b")
>>>
```

It's also not working with a numbered group:

```
>>> re.match(r"(\d)(?(1)a|b)", "5a")
<re.Match object; span=(0, 2), match='5a'>
>>> re.match(r"(\d)(?(1)a|b)", "b")
>>>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the group at the start of the pattern is required to match.  You can fix it by making it optional (adding a `?` after it):

```
>>> re.match(r"(?P<x>\d)?(?(x)a|b)", "5a")
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 2), match='5a'>
>>> 

>>> re.match(r"(?P<x>\d)?(?(x)a|b)", "b")
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 1), match='b'>
>>>
```

Comment: Argh, right. The conditional is never evaluated because ```b``` has already failed to match, without the ```?```. I think I botched my example trying to simplify it. I probably should have asked about the full pattern, but I found another way to do it.